# Printing nodes smoothly from linkedlist

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, linked-list, nodes

I'm adding info from a text file into nodes and then creating a linked list, which I then print out, but I'm having problems. I print the nodes and it comes out perfect but when I add it to a list and print out the list, I'm getting constant repetition and it takes about 6 hours to go through the list when it should take at most 20 seconds, it moves through the info in the list eventually but repeats some info about 500 times before it moves on, all the while repeating the all the previous info the same number of times. Here's my `add` and `print` function:

```
void customerlist::add(customer* ustomer)
{
    customer* p = new customer;
    p = ustomer;
    p->next = NULL;
    if (head != 0)
    {
        curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = p;
        n++;
    }
    else
    {
        head = p;
    }
}

int customerlist::getLength()
{
    return n;
}

void customerlist::print()
{
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        cout << curr->ID << " ";
        cout << curr->name << "  " << curr->lastname << "  " << curr->town << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

My main:

```
while (!in.eof())
{
    account* bank = new account;
    customer* ustomer; in >> ustomer->ID;
    // display number of customers
    if (ustomer->ID < 90000000)
    {
        count++;
        in >> ustomer->name >> ustomer->lastname >> ustomer->town;
        // cout << ustomer->ID<< " " << ustomer->name << "  " << ustomer->lastname<< "        "         << ustomer->town << endl ;
        ustomerlist.add(ustomer);
        ustomerlist.print();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing out the entire list every time you add an element to it.  So you're actually printing #elements factorial lines.  Move the ustomerlist.print() to just before the break.

Edit - as other posters have pointed out, the print issue is far from the most important problem with your code, but the above change should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, lets list some of the immediate problems:

In the `add` function you allocate memory and assign it to `p`, then you directly reassign `p` to point to where `ustomer` is pointing, making you loose the memory you allocate.

In the `main` function you should not do `while(!in.eof())`, because the `eofbit` flag isn't set until you try to read from beyond the file you will iterate once to many. Instead do e.g.

```
while (in >> name >> lastname >> town) { ... }
```

And then you have the worst problem of all: [*Undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because you have the pointer `ustomer` but you never initialize that pointer, you never make it point anywhere.

The solution to the last problem can also solve the first problem (the memory leak): Instead of allocating anode in the `add` function, allocate a node in the loop and use that, as is, in the add function.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the print function "repeats" info before it "moves on". Here is why:

As you add more nodes, all previous nodes will be printed out, so when you add the N-th node, you will have printed (N^2)/2 items, with the M-th node being repeated N-M times (it's *quadratic* rather than *factorial*). So by the time you have five customers say A B C D E, you will have seen:

```
A 
A B 
A B C 
A B C D 
A B C D E
```

Instead, every time you add a new node,  print that new node instead of the whole list.

Consider this logic in your main:

```
main(){
    count = 0;
    tail = head;
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        customer *new_customer;
        in >>  new_customer->ID;
        //check ID against defined MAX instead of a hard coded #
        if(new_customer->ID < MAX_ID) {
            count ++;
            in >> new_customer->name >> new_customer->lastname >> new_customer->town;

            tail->next = new_customer;
            tail = tail->next;
            tail->next = NULL;
            // here, print each new node using cout, so you will have the complete list as you add
            cout << new_customer->name << " " << blah blah << endl;

            // unless there's a specific need to print the entire list every time, use:  
            // customerlist.print(); 
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```